# Is it possible to have comments in multiline commands in fish?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, fish

In `bash` it's possible to do

```
my_function() {
  echo "hello" |
  #remove 'l'
  tr -d 'l'
}
```

but in `fish` ( http://fishshell.com ) I wasn't able to do the same:

```
function my_function
  echo "hello" | \
  # remove 'l' 
  tr -d 'l'
end
```

I've tried with backslash at the end of the comment too but no luck.

I tend to use this idiom a lot in `bash`, piping several commands and splitting each command in its own line with a commment for each.

Is there any way to achieve something similar in `fish`?

Comment: I've not heard of FiPL before, but apparently it uses c-style comments: `/* this is a comment */` I'm not sure if that makes a difference? **EDIT** Oh wait, you mean "friendly interactive shell", ignore me :)

Comment: I believe it's something that was missed while making the grammar. I reported the bug at https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/983.

Comment: @xfix, as ridiculousfish, the Fish core developer confirmed it is a bug I would post this comment as the answer to allow to accept it and mark this question as solved (i.e. not possible as of Fish 2.1.0).

Comment: @Szpak: Done. Also, the reason why I put it in bug tracker was not to confirm it (it was already confirmed by this thread), but to add it to TODO list, so other developers would know it (and if somebody would want to, he could make a pull request - but don't bother doing this for this issue, because of ast branch - unless you are going to do this to ast branch, which is really unstable, and has many known issues).

Comment: Sure, I understand it. I just proposed to make this question closed to not show up on the unanswered question list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible because of the bug reported at https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/983.

However, [there are works on real fish grammar (as opposed to quick hacky parser) in ast branch of fish-shell repository](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/tree/ast) ([now merged, but disabled by default](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/557#issuecomment-32216634)). Currently, there is no patch to support this syntax, but it's still work in progress, and I'm almost sure that the final grammar will have support for this.